# Downsides to Using the Same Value for Key and IV?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I am implementing some classes for .NET that (among other things) simplify encryption and decryption.

My current algorithm creates an 8-byte salt, and uses that salt with the password to generate both the key and IV. I then store the salt, unencrypted, with my encrypted data.

This is nice because the salt appears to always be 8 bytes and that's all the overhead it adds to my encrypted data. However, is there any downside to using the same value for both my key and IV? Is there a better way?

Relevant code:

```
SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = CreateAlgorithm();
byte[] salt = CreateSalt();
byte[] keyBytes = DeriveBytes(salt, algorithm.KeySize >> 3);
byte[] ivBytes = DeriveBytes(salt, algorithm.BlockSize >> 3);
```

Supporting code:

```
private static readonly int SaltLength = 8;

internal byte[] CreateSalt()
{
    byte[] salt = new byte[SaltLength];
    using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider generator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        generator.GetBytes(salt);
    }
    return salt;
}

public byte[] DeriveBytes(byte[] salt, int bytes)
{
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes derivedBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Password, salt, 1000);
    return derivedBytes.GetBytes(bytes);
}
```

Comment: Related: [Problems with using AES Key as IV in CBC-Mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16161/problems-with-using-aes-key-as-iv-in-cbc-mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, as long as you use a new, randomly created salt for each message, you are close to what I might do.  The random salt means the IV will change with each new message, and this means that the exact same message will be different crypto-text each transmission.  All good.  The one thing I would change if I were you is instead of using DeriveBytes to get the key and then to get the IV, I would have DeriveBytes give a set of bytes the size of the key and IV together, then split them and use them separately.  The IV should not have to be secret from anyone.  The key must be.  So if you DeriveBytes once from the same salt and password, then split those bytes into key and IV, the attacker is still no closer to knowing the key after looking at the IV than he was before.

Alternatively, you could use a nonce to create a known permutation between the IV bytes and the key bytes.  For example, excuse my pseudocode:

```
IV = DeriveBytes(salt + password + "IV")
key = DeriveBytes(salt + password + "key")
```

Either way is secure.  But I would just DeriveBytes on, say, 32 bytes and then use 16 of them for the IV and 16 of them for the key.  There is no information in the first 16 bytes that will help an attacker calculate the next 16 bytes.

Comment: If it's secure, I like your first suggestion. It's easy to implement and doesn't increase the amount of data I must store with my encrypted data.

Comment: If you didn't need / want to salt the password, you could just use CTR mode with AES.  I believe .NET lacks an implementation, but it is easy enough to do.  Believe it or not, Wikipedia has a decent explanation of it.  And it makes AES into a stream cipher.  Properly implemented it would eliminate virtually all overhead on crypto transmission for you.

Comment: Just to give you a quick explanation, CTR uses a fixed nonce and a counter to generate the "plaintext".  With each transmission of data, you increment your counter and concatenate it with the nonce and encrypt it ECB mode.  The counter ensures that each encryption will be totally different from any preceding.  Then you XOR this output with your block of plaintext to get your ciphertext.  Put another way, you put the nonce plus counter through the crypto to get a bunch of tiny one-time-pads.  Your plaintext does not need to be padded -- you just throw away as much of the OTP as you didn't need.

Comment: I just thought I should comment one more time to assure you it is indeed secure.  Consider that for all plain texts, their hashes are distributed uniformly over the hash output space.  Then if someone knows the first 16 bytes of a 256 bit hash, all he can know about the last 16 bytes is that any possibility is a valid output of the hash function.  He just does not know which one is your key.  It's like the OTP problem where the attacker does not lack decryptions; in fact he has too many of them (every one that fits the message space), each as "valid" as the next.

Comment: Well, I have skills in a number of different areas, but understanding cryptography and security are not one of them. So there are parts of that comment that I don't understand. But based on all the discussions I've had (with you and others), this seems like a reasonably secure approach. And all the caller of my classes need is a password to make it go, which was my original goal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it defeats the purpose of the IV. The IV is used so if you encrypt the same message with the same key you don't get the same ciphertext. You might as well just use a constant value of `0`, it adds the same amount of security.

Answer (score 1):

In your case here you are using the same value for your

- Key
- IV

Conceptually this is a bad idea because the IV is supposed to be non-secret, and different for each encryption. You've solved the *"different for each encryption"*, but you have it identical to your key.

The thing you're trying to defend against is making sure that two encryptions with the same key will not give the same ciphertext. In your case, this will only happen if the RNG generates two identical 128-bit AES keys.

While the odds of this are low, you should just not have it.